# Algorithm to find a form of some Sum of Square

Tags: inequality, optimization, contest-math, square-numbers

So, there is this problem from Indonesian math olympiad (OSP 2022 no. 3) that bugs me.

We were given that $x$ and $y$ are real numbers that satisfy
$$5x^2 + 4xy + 11y^2 = 3$$

**Without calculus**, find the maximum of

$$xy - 2x + 5y$$

One of the solution is short, but is some kind of black magic. Basically, it goes like this.

$$
\begin{align*}
3 &= 5x^2 + 4xy + 11y^2 \\
  &= 5x^2 + 2xy + 2xy + 11y^2 \\
  &= 5x^2 + 2xy + 2(k + 2x - 5y) + 11y^2 \\
  &= 5x^2 + 2xy + 2k + 4x - 10y + 11y^2
\end{align*}
$$

And then *somehow* it skips to

$$xy - 2x + 5y = \frac{13}{4} - \frac{1}{2}((2x + 1)^2 + (x + y)^2 + 10(y - \frac{1}{2})^2)$$

and it is obvious that $\frac{13}{4}$ is the answer.

What I am asking is **not** how to find the answer to this problem, rather how or what algorithm to find the **form** of the sum of square. Is it just by pure luck?

Like... *what kind of intuition will help me find this form?*

One can brute force or even do something like:

$$k = m - \frac{1}{a}((bx + c)^2 + (cx + e)^2 + z(...)^2)$$

and then match the coefficient. But, I ain't no way solving that ridiculous thing.

Or maybe, first use calculus to get the desired $x$ and $y$, and then set up the form. But, that is some sort of inorganic.

Is there any way to do it? Can AM–GM, Muirhead, Cauchy–Schwarz help?

Comment: Well...knowing that there is meant to be some non-calculus proof, it is certainly natural to look for something like this.  Personally, I'd  multiply the objective function by $4$ to get $4xy-8x+20y=3-5x^2-11y^2-8x+20y$ and then complete the squares in both $x$ and $y$.  The point, of course, being to kill off the cross term.

Comment: @CalvinLin Alternatively, we can do completing the squares. If we know that $Max = 13/4$ when $x = -1/2, y = 1/2$ (or guess these), it is easy. Otherwise, I am afraid we need some calculating.

Comment: Oh that is true. It's not as simple as completing the square for the expression. We still have to ensure that $(x,y)$ lies on the parabola @lulu.  EG The max of $ 3 - 5x^2 - 11y^2 - 8x + 20y$ is actually $841/55$, occurring at $ (-4/5, 10/11)$.

Comment: @CalvinLin Yes. A question is how can we guess the maximum (even during the contest)? By the way, you may use @. I did not receive notification.

Comment: @RiverLi Yes I'm aware. Only 1 person can be notified in each comment, so I chose to notify lulu instead because that approach doesn't work out easily.

Comment: @CalvinLin I see. I think that approach does not work.

Comment: @FaranAiki Is the answer $\dfrac{13}{4}$ or $\dfrac{31}{4}$?

Comment: @YNK I am copying the problem and the answer verbatim.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without calculus.

From

$$
\cases{
f = x y - 2 x + 5y\\
5x^2+4 x y+11 y^2= 3
}
$$

eliminating $y$ we obtain

$$
11 f^2+f (4 x+64) x+5 x^4+58 x^3+206 x^2-30 x-75 = 0
$$

now as $f$ is such that is tangent to the restriction we have

$$
11 f^2+f (4 x+64) x+5 x^4+58 x^3+206 x^2-30 x-75 = (x-x_1)^2(a x^2+ b x + c)
$$

there must be a double root $x_1$ due to tangency. Now equating coefficients

$$
\cases{
5-a = 0\\
2 a x_1-b+58 = 0\\
-a x_1^2+2 b x_1-c+4 f+206=0\\
-b x_1^2+2 c x_1+64 f-30=0\\
-c x_1^2+11 f^2-75=0
}
$$

and with some guess work we obtain two solutions

$$
\left[
\begin{array}{ccccc}
f & a & b & c & x_1\\
 10 & 5 & 8 & 41 & -5 \\
 \frac{13}{4} & 5 & 53 & \frac{659}{4} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
\end{array}
\right]
$$

Comment: You have written $f= xy - 2x - 5y$. Is this a typo or a mistake?

Comment: It is a typo. Thanks! Now it is fixed.

Comment: Well... I kind of lost at "eliminating y".

Comment: First $xy = f+2x-5y$ and after that $y =\frac{f+2x}{x-5} $ both into the restriction.